# Changing to env:flex in app.yaml introduces a redirect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cors

After receiving an email from google reporting that the `vm: true` configuration in appengine flexible environments should be replaced by `env: flex`, apps that use custom domains are now responding with a HTTP 307 temporary redirect, which points to the -.appspot.com url.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

This seems to be problematic when dealing with OPTIONS requests since those requests are no longer handled by my code.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See Adam's comment below this answer for newer information.

This issue is currently being tracked in the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13406). Feel free to follow that thread for updates on this.

Comment: As an update from the linked issue, you can now [apply to be whitelisted](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#domain_update) for custom domains on the new appspot-preview.com and avoid the redirect.